# Mysql order by on column with unicode characters

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I am running a select query on mysql table and trying to order it by the "name" column in the table.
The name column contains both English character names and names with Latin character like â.
I am running into the below problem.
The query I run returns the results ordered in the below manner i.e.
Eg: if Name contains "archer", "aaakash", "â hayden", "bourne", "jason"
The results returned by the query is ordered as below
"aaakash", "archer", "â hayden", "bourne", "jason"

However I want to order it based on unicode code points (like below)
"aaakash", "archer", "bourne", "jason", "â hayden"

(See the difference in the position of â hayden in the orders)
What can I do to order the results based on the character's position in unicode character set?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988249/mysql-5-1-61-sorting-for-central-european-languages-in-utf8

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> However I want to order it based on unicode code points (like below)

To sort using unicode code point, you probably need to use `utf8_bin` collation.

Precisely, the `_bin` suffix indicate to sort by the *binary representation of each character*.

---

To *override* the default collation while ordering, you will use [`ORDER BY ... COLLATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html):

To paraphrase the documentation:

```
SELECT k
FROM t1
ORDER BY k COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

*If* your text column does *not* use utf8 encoding, you will have to [`CONVERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html) it:

```
SELECT k
FROM t1
ORDER BY CONVERT(k USING utf8) COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

<sub>Please notice I used `utf8` as an example here as this is the most common Unicode encoding. But your MySQL server probably support other Unicode encoding, like [`ucs2`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16)("UTF-16").</sub>

Comment: you can read more about it here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-binary-collations.html. if you mean on byte level with "unicode code points" you should use utf8_bin.

Comment: @RaymondN considering the character range implied, `ucs2` (16-bit, fixed length) seems to be a valid Unicode encoding for that purpose too. Or do I missed something?