# MYSQL query did not order results mix char

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table with id, surname etc., when I query order by surname I obtain something like this

```
A, B, C,... V, Z, Ć, Č, Č, Đ ...
```

where slavian char are ordered after finished western european alphabet

Mysql connection is set in utf-8. query is

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY SURNAME ASC
```

how can i obtain an unique order like

```
A, B, C, Ć, Č, Č, Đ... V, Z
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql order by on column with unicode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18210189/mysql-order-by-on-column-with-unicode-characters)

Answer (score 0):

in this case you need to define your own Alphabet (or Order). To do so you can follow [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378613/how-to-define-a-custom-order-by-order-in-mysql).

Hopefully it works with non-ascii signs.

Comment: Not my case Shuumi thanks, this one is a grouped query ut i habe nothin to group...

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to use proper collation, which provides necessary info about ordering strings. Here's how to use `collate` keyword:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY SURNAME COLLATE latin1_german2_ci
```

Here I used `latin1_german2_ci` as an example, find collation that matches your requirements.

[Supported Character Sets and Collations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html)

Comment: Thank Michal but when i try this mysql error is
#1253 - COLLATION 'latin2_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8'

Comment: Try other collation, that was just an example

Comment: I know it, in fact if you see I used another colllation! The real problem is that i have the table in charset utf8...

Comment: I solved using 
ORDER BY convert(surname using cp852) COLLATE cp852_general_ci
Thank you very much

Comment: @LucaFrassineti If my answer helped you finding solution, mark it as accepted (green check mark on the left) and optionally upvote :) Glad I could help